# Hot to turn a netbook home server's screen off after inactivity?

Tags: debian, command-line

I'm building a simple home server from an old notebook (Acer Aspire One 722). It's running Debian 10.7, without any graphical interface -- It's pure CLI. I want my server to turn it's screen off after some inactivity, and the best that I managed to achieve was to modify [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1312192) solution like that:

```
[Unit]
Description=Enable virtual console blanking
 
[Service]
Type=oneshot
Environment=TERM=linux
StandardOutput=tty
TTYPath=/dev/console
ExecStart=/usr/bin/setterm --blank 1 --powersave on --powerdown 2
 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The screen goes blank after a minute, as the `--blank 1` parameter states, but no matter how much I wait, the `--powersave on --powerdown 2` does not seem to work at all. I notice that my final installation was really bare bones (I've had to manually install the man pages!), so maybe there is some package missing?